# Gerrit patch comparision for Sql files

Tags: gerrit

I am using Gerrit for code review for all the SQL files that is being used in the Project. Gerrit is hosted on Linux machine and its version is 2.6.1.

I have problem in comparing SQL patch set and all the SQL files are considered to a binary file by Gerrit and hence unable to provide the comparison.

For reference, following is the response on Gerrit comparison:

> diff --git a/web/dev-db/sp/dbo.usp_getactivityownerlist.sql b/web/dev-db/sp/dbo.usp_getactivityownerlist.sql
>   index f623dd3..e2ed93b 100644
>   --- a/web/dev-db/sp/dbo.usp_getactivityownerlist.sql
>   +++ b/web/dev-db/sp/dbo.usp_getactivityownerlist.sql
>   Binary files differ

Is there any way I can configure Gerrit to consider .SQL file as a text file rather than binary file so that patch comparison is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to your `$repo/.git/info/attributes:`

```
*.sql crlf diff
```

It normally happens when user set `core.autocrlf` to `false` in global config file. This effectively disabled "smart" detection of line endings in text files.

It can be encoding issue as well, Git works best with `utf-8`, if the encoding is in something like `utf-16,` Git will think it's binary, no matter what you set in `.gitattributes`

Comment: This is not solving the problem since this is really pointing to Git. But what we really need is to somehow configure Gerrit Server to understand the same thing and understand .sql file as text file so that comparison can be easy within Gerrit for any sql patch.